# How can I see the RRC state and signal level of an HTC Explorer?

Tags: dialer-codes, htc-explorer

Is there any alternative to the Android secret code `*#*#197328640#*#*` for the HTC Explorer? I am trying to get the same Service Mode on my HTC Explorer to show the RRC State and signal level of the device.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that we all know what that code does. Can you provide some details as to what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get RRC State, Signal level of the device. There is another code *#0011#. This code is providing the above mentioned details on Samsung S2 but no results are shown on HTC EXPLORER.

Comment: Those are details you should add to the question. Comments, by their very nature, are impermanent.

Comment: You could try `*#*#7378423#*#*` (aka `*#*#SERVICE#*#*`).

Comment: @Izzy Like the codes that I have mentioned earlier this code is also not showing any result.

Comment: Is there any other way to determine RRC State of the device?

Comment: What is RRC? Is the settings > About Phone > Signal Strength not enough? on Gingerbread/ICS it reports -83 dBm 15asu... Why the specifically RRC? Maybe its not *visible*...

Comment: BTW - just read this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Resource_Control) There may be no known way of accessing that information as that is at the baseband/firmware level, mind me asking - where did you see that originally from?

Answer (score 1):

On most Android phones, the code `*#*#4636#*#*` provides network information such as signal level and preferred networks. However I am unsure of what you mean by displaying that information within the HTC Explorer.

Comment: I have tried this option on HTC Explorer and it's working fine but it's not giving RRC State of the device.