# Is there any way to determine the UMTS RRC state my device is in

Tags: phone-app, dialer-codes

I want to determine the RRC state of my device which is *HTC Explorer*.
By RRC, I mean states like FACH,DCH IDLE etc..
I have already tried the following secret codes:

```
*#*#197328640#*#*
*#*#7378423#*#* 
*#*#4636#*#*
```

Unfortunately, these codes are working on few Samsung devices and I am able to determine the RRC state of the respective device but, none of them is working on my Device-HTC Explorer with android version 2.3.5.

Comment: Is this the same question as posted previously *How can I see the RRC state and signal level of an HTC Explorer?* [Link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41607/how-can-i-see-the-rrc-state-and-signal-level-of-an-htc-explorer) - If you're the same OP, why are you double-posting?

Comment: I am a new user.Also,I am not following the above mentioned post.

Comment: Although,I have just now read the mentioned post..Unfortunately,still no solution to my issue.Kindly provide the relevant information